# Файлы в корне поддомена

Tags: apache, php

Приветствую!

Сайт на домене domain.ru, апач настроен так, что по домену privet.domain.ru открывается тот же код, но выводится информация, соответствующая поддомену. Поддомены динамические.

Сейчас файл **robots.txt** для домена domain.ru показывается тот же, что и для поддомена privet.domain.ru, а нужно чтобы для поддомена был свой файл.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей?

ЗЫ: Статические файлы вроде robots.txt могут быть любые.

Вопрос решен самостоятельно, решение вот
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.ru$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/_domain_static/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_domain_static/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]`

Поясню: статические файлы поддомена открываются из отдельной директории, общие файлы исключаюся и берутся из корня основного домена.

Comment: RewriteRule + RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} не устроит?

Comment: Устроит, но не получается составить условие.

Нужно что-то вроде такого: Если это файл и он в корне, то достать его из папки /some_dir/privet.domain.ru/robots.txt

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно не получается. Вы условия чётко сформулировать можете, на нормальном языке, безо всяких рерайтеров? Если да - в студию, переведём :)

P.S. Проверка файла:

`RewriteCond /some_dir/privet.domain.ru/robots.txt -f`

Comment: Еще раз.

Есть domain.ru, есть privet.domain.ru.

Оба адреса обращаются в одну и ту же папку и на уровне php выводятся данные соответствующие адресу данные.

Css и js единые для всех и запрашиваются из папки в корне.

Еще есть статические файлы, например robots.txt, которые должны показываться ТОЛЬКО на privet.domain.ru. Вот вопрос в том, как их выводить.

Допустим что эти статические файлы лежат в папке /some_dir/privet.domain.ru/. Пользователю этот путь не надо знать
Он запрашивает /robots.txt, а получает содержимое /some_dir/privet.domain.ru/robots.txt

Имена файлов могут быть любыми.

Comment: Дополню, что условие должно быть именно для файлов в корне, т.е. файлы в папке /css не должны запрашиваться.

Вот поэтому не получается.

Comment: Всё равно не очень понятно, что мешает сделать нечто вроде:


    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} privet.domain.ru
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /privet.domain.ru-robots.txt

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.ru
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /domain.ru-robots.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond /robot-files/%{HTTP_HOST}-robots.txt !-f
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robot-files/default-robots.txt

RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robot-files/%{HTTP_HOST}-robots.txt
```

может так? раз домены динамические.

Comment: Последняя строка подойдет, если будет работать для динамического имени файла.

первые 2 строки не понял

Comment: Перевожу :) Если нет файла `/robot-files/%{HTTP_HOST}-robots.txt` используем `/robot-files/default-robots.txt`, в противном случае - файл `/robot-files/%{HTTP_HOST}-robots.txt`